# HTML Webpage Sidebars Acting Up

Tags: html, css

Help, have been working for hours on this HTML Page. I've been viewing it in Chrome, but when I resize the page I notice that the sidebars I've added cover up everything.

Here is what I wanted to do:

Have a scroll bar when the page is resized (Keeping the page the same)

Have one side bar one side, and to be able to slide over the page to find the other scroll bar. (I dont want the. covering everything up like they are now..)

Here is the code:

```css
#img1 {
  width: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#container1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#heading-contain {
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: "adam", arial;
  color: white;
}
#heading2 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
#heading1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
#heading2 h3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 6px;
  color: DarkSlateGrey;
}
#main-content {
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: LightSlateGrey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#text1 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  line-height: 200%;
}
#name {
  color: DarkSeaGreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "dragon is coming";
  font-size: 300%;
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/X5kjAhye8_5IE9Ws3Z0e05aIAsP_jCSbsh1hja0nNdF8GczkNd0aZQEe7w1V5-2B-9k=h900");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#footer {
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
  color: white;
  border: 1px double white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "adam";
  font-weight: bold;
}
#footer p {
  margin: 5px;
}
#name:hover {
  color: LightCoral;
  cursor: default;
}
#line1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#paragraph {
  text-indent: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sidebar-left {
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "adam";
  color: white;
}
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
  background-color: LightSlateGrey;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
}
#sidebar-right {
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "adam";
  color: white;
}
#sidebar-right h4 {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#sidebar-right img {
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#sidebar-right p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML WEBPAGE 2 | Brett Carwile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <!-- Container1 contains all the elements on the page !-->
    <div id="heading-contain">
      <!-- Heading-container contains everything in the header !-->
      <div id="heading1">
        <!-- Heading1 is the top of the header which includes the h1 !-->
        <h1>HTML Webpage 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="heading2">
        <!-- Heading2 is the bottom half of the header including the h3 !-->
        <h3>By Brett Carwile</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-right">
      <h4>About the Author</h4>
      <img src="DSC00071.jpg">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ullamcorper gravida facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed dui diam. Nulla facilisi. Donec rhoncus dolor malesuada urna commodo lacinia. Sed vel nisi
        venenatis, aliquet nibh at, lobortis lacus. Etiam enim lacus, venenatis a sagittis ac, rhoncus in velit. Pellentesque turpis massa, condimentum eget eleifend non, sit amet justo. Vivamus accumsan iaculis placerat. Quisque blandit diam ut risus
        ultrices rutrum. Mauris pretium in augue ut lobortis. Vivamus tempor ac nisl at euismod. Maecenas laoreet a erat a varius. Curabitur consequat nunc vehicula tellus ornare, vitae aliquet sapien varius.
      </P>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-left">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>Check out the awesome links above!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id=main-content>
      <!-- This div is the main area below the header (text, img ect...) !-->
      <p id="text1">
        <!-- This span is to seperate the first line from the rest of the text !-->
        <span id="line1"> This is an HTML webpage by <span id="name">Brett Carwile</span>.</span>
        <br>
        <!-- This span is so that we can indent the text !-->
        <span id="paragraph">This is a text sample. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id quam nulla. Nam sollicitudin porta ligula, sit amet pharetra elit tincidunt sit amet. Suspendisse rhoncus, elit at consectetur sagittis, nisi eros molestie urna, et cursus elit sapien quis ante. Sed sit amet pulvinar neque. Pellentesque eget lorem ac lorem sodales rutrum. Nulla erat nisl, consequat non ante vitae, porttitor convallis magna. Duis pulvinar ornare nisi nec varius. Mauris tempus nisi non viverra vulputate. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas vestibulum viverra erat eu rhoncus.

    Cras nec vulputate leo. Donec nunc mauris, varius id ligula eu, tincidunt euismod lorem. Praesent pharetra, ipsum et congue egestas, sapien augue feugiat lacus, ac tincidunt augue leo ut tortor. Mauris efficitur urna ut turpis ornare, eu consectetur lacus dapibus. Curabitur sit amet justo blandit est fermentum volutpat. Sed in gravida nunc. Integer sit amet risus in justo porttitor cursus. Mauris tortor purus, viverra a lacus et, suscipit molestie tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </span>
      </p>
      <img src="DSC00071.jpg" id="img1">
      <div id="footer">
        <p>Thank you for viewing!!! © Brett Carwile 2016</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

You can try the HTML/CSS and resize the window to see what I mean.

Comment: Try giving the side bar a max-width

Answer (score 0):

Adding min-width to the body element and removing the position fixed for the sidebar-left and sidebar-right will make the trick. Please see below the modified css rules.

```
body {
    min-width: 1200px; //Modify depending on your requirements
    background-image: url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/X5kjAhye8_5IE9Ws3Z0e05aIAsP_jCSbsh1hja0nNdF8GczkNd0aZQEe7w1V5-2B-9k=h900");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#sidebar-left {
    background-color: LightSeaGreen;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: "adam";
    color: white;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background-color: LightSeaGreen;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: "adam";
    color: white;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but nope... You see, I want the sidebars to stick in the same spot when I scroll up and down. Removing position:fixed; makes them only fit the screen when it is scrolled all the way up. (When you scroll down they don't stay.) For the resizing thing.... It worked, I could scroll to the side, but the right sidebar was out of place...... (Like i need something that will give it a position fixed for scrolling up and down, but not for side to side) sorry if that sounded confusing. IDK.... what to do. I need to have this figured out by tomorrow to show my teacher.......

Comment: I don't think you can make it with html and css only. One way would be to leave the sidebars as position absolute and using JavaScript you can stick them at the top of the screen on the scroll event.